# Proof Gambling Systems Don't Work

Tags: probability

How do you prove that a "system" where you vary your bet size from one trial to the next cannot help you beat an unfavorable game?  For concreteness, just assume the game is roulette and you are betting on "red" each time.  Also assume that the bet sizes are in discrete units like dollars, and that there's a minimum and a maximum bet limit.  You are free to vary your bet size between those limits however you like based on past outcomes.

Comment: http://www.math.utah.edu/~levin/M5040/mg.pdf

Comment: In roulette, every bet has a negative expectation.

Comment: I believe that is correct

Comment: @Lorenzo  thanks for those notes.  I assume that to make that analysis apply to an unfavorable game, you just replace some equal signs with less than signs.  Is there a way to go from the conclusion that, on average, things go poorly, to the more interesting conclusion that, almost surely, things will go poorly if you keep playing?

Comment: If you can formulate a precise question capturing your intuition, try opening a new question here. There are a lot of theorems about the convergence of martingales and stopping times (when you run out of money), and so on...

Comment: OK good suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: From an intuitive pov, think about making 100, 1 dollar bets or 10, 10 dollar bets. Your expected loss is the same however, you are more likely to end up with a bigger loss or gain with the latter approach and the former approach is more likely to produce a loss with a smaller spread around the expected, totol loss of just under $6.